# how can i convert a struts1 compatible class to strut2 class

Tags: response, public

public ActionForward execute(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form,
            HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
{

}

Answer (score 0):

public String execute() {

return "someString"
}